# How to kill IEDriverServer on parallel execution?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
public void closeBrowsers(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            driver.close();
            WindowsUtils.killByName("IEDriverServer.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM iexpore.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM iexpore *32.exe");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

This is method i am calling on AfterTest..

When run sequential it is working fine.. But when running parallel, it is failing and sometime the running test case browser gets closed and failed.. If I am not killing, the app gets slowness over the period time..

How to handle when running parallel execution?

Comment: Why not using the efficient and proven `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()` along with `taskkill`?

Comment: but still it will close all browser which is running in parallel